# php - how to return an associative array items with certain keys only?

Tags: php, arrays

There is an associative array:

```
    Array
   (
    [tableData] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [booking_name] => abc/xyz/123
                [user_area] => ls reca
                [release] => oss72
                [start_date] => 2017-06-20 00:00:00
                [end_date] => 2017-06-23 00:00:00
                [asset_info] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [status] => 10
                                [manufacturer] => HP
                                [model] => HP BL460C GEN8
                                [hardware_color] => #0066b3
                            )

                    )

                [full_name] => Valay Desai
                [email_address] => valay@xyz.com
            )
            ............,
            [500] => Array()
        )
)
```

I've used `array_map` to get the attribute name from another object (`$filtered_array)`.

```
$filteredColumns = array_map(function($item){
        return $item['attribute'];
    }, $filtered_array);
```

From this I got below output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => booking_name
    [5] => asset_info
    [6] => full_name
    [7] => start_date
)
```

Here keys are not in order. And `asset_info` is another associative array.

```
$filteredData = [];

    foreach ($tableData as $key => $row) {
        $filteredData[$key] = array_filter($filteredColumns, function($item) use ($row){
            $intersect = array_intersect_assoc((array)$item, (array)$row);
            return (count($intersect)) === count($row);
        });
    }
```

But got blank array as output.

**How do I return main big associative array only with keys name I got it with `array_map` ? How do I return main array (500 items) with items that matches certain keys only ?**

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote ?

Comment: Can you make an example with input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see a need to use array_filter. If you flip $filteredColumns (so the column names are the array keys) you can simply use array_intersect_key() to get only the required keys.

```
$filteredColumns = array_flip($filteredColumns);

foreach ($tableData as $key => $row) {
    $filteredData[$key] = array_intersect_key($row, $filteredColumns);
}
```

And depending on how $filtered_array looks, you could probably use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php instead of the array_map

Comment: could you please help me out with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721195/php-how-can-i-filter-associative-array-of-arrays-with-use-of-an-array-as-condi