# Filter multidimensional array using multiple rules from another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have a multidimensional input array and another multidimensional array containing rules by which to filter the input array.

```
$array = [
    'tableData' => [
        [
            'booking_name' => 'abc/xyz/123',
            'pdg' => 'assure',
            'user_area' => 'es st',
            'release' => 'oss72',
            'start_date' => '2017-06-20 00:00:00',
            'end_date' => '2017-06-23 00:00:00',
            'asset_info' => [
                [
                    'status' => 10,
                    'manufacturer' => 'HP',
                    'model' => 'HP BL460C GEN8',
                    'hardware_color' => ''#0066b3'
                ]
            ],
            'full_name' => 'Valay Desai',
            'email_address' => 'valay@xyz.com'
        ],
        [
            'booking_name' => 'abc/xyz/123',
            'pdg' => 'assure',
            'user_area' => 'ls reca',
            'release' => 'oss72',
            'start_date' => '2017-06-20 00:00:00',
            'end_date' => '2017-06-23 00:00:00',
            'asset_info' => [
                [
                    'status' => 10,
                    'manufacturer' => 'SUN',
                    'model' => 'SUN GEN8',
                    'hardware_color' => '#0066b3'
                ]
            ],
            'full_name' => 'Chako Desai',
            'email_address' => 'chako@xyz.com'
        ]
    ]
];

$filterBy = [
    'booking_name' => 'abc',
    'pdg' => [
        ['name' => 'Invalid', 'value' => 'Invalid'],
        ['name' => 'assure', 'value' => 'assure']
    ],
    'user_area' => [
        ['name' => 'es st', 'value' => 'es st'],
        ['name' => 'Invalid', 'value' => 'Invalid'],
        ['name' => 'a&o', 'value' => 'a&o']
    ]
];
```

I understand that `array_filter` can be used to compare the values, but I'm not sure how to perform the multi-rule filtration on the data within `tableData`.

Ideal output should be the first element from `tableData` because it has `booking_name=abc`, `pdg=assure` and `user_area=es st`.

I tried with:

```
// bigarray is an originial array to be filtered
// filterObj is an array with multiple filter conditions
array_filter($bigarray, function ($val_array) use ($filterObj) {
    $intersection = array_intersect_assoc($val_array, $filterObj);
    return (count($intersection)) === count($filterObj);
});
```

This always returns blank array.

**Update 1:**

I've used below way to get objects who has `visible:true`. Tried similar for the asked question but couldn't able to get the ideal result.

```
$columnVisible = array(
    'visible' => 1,
);

$visibleColumns = array_filter($passedColumns, function ($val_array) use ($columnVisible) {
    $intersection = array_intersect_assoc($val_array, $columnVisible);
    return (count($intersection)) === count($columnVisible);
});
```

How do I apply multiple filtering conditions passed as an array of arrays on an associative array of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
$filters = array('pdg'=>array('xyzabc'), 'user_area'=>array('ls reca'));
$filter_items = array();
foreach( $items['tableData'] as $item ){
    $i=0;
    $is_match = true;


 foreach( $filters as $key=>$value){
    //$is_match = true;
    if( !in_array( $item[$key], $value) ){
        $is_match = false;
        break;
    }
    //$is_match = true;
 }

 if( $is_match ){
    $filter_items[] = $item;
 }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work with provided filters of array. However this works fine in a format you have given for the filters ($filters).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would bother trying to wrangle `array_intersect()`-family functions for this task.  These functions perform sorting while they iterate and this is not going to be ideal while returing pass/fail type evaluations.

I would simplify the filtering array's structure to make the processing more direct.  Once the `pdg` and `user_area` rules are flattened to their most meaningful parts, just call `array_filter()` and write the three evaluations in a single return. This will enjoy the performance benefit of "short circuiting" so as soon as a `false` outcome is encountered, the `false` will be returned without making needless extra evaluations.

I am nesting the output inside of a `tableData` although I don't know if that's the exact output you desire.  It is simple enough to unwrap the filtered array from the element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4paXE))

```
$filterBy['pdg'] = array_column($filterBy['pdg'], 'value');
$filterBy['user_area'] = array_column($filterBy['user_area'], 'value');

var_export(
    [
        'tableData' => 
        array_filter(
            $array['tableData'],
            function($row) use($filterBy) {
                return str_contains($row['booking_name'], $filterBy['booking_name'])
                    && in_array($row['pdg'], $filterBy['pdg'])
                    && in_array($row['user_area'], $filterBy['user_area']);
            }
        )
    ]
);
```